# Upload from git format-patch to ReviewBoard fails on "file not found in the repository"

Tags: git, review-board, format-patch

Has anyone seen the complaint `The file “<file>” (revision <revision>) was not found in the repository` when using the ReviewBoard GUI?

E.g. I get 
 `The file "agent/src/com/cloud/agent/resource/HypervResource.java" (revision 8b8e89d) was not found in the repository` when uploading a diff file created with `git format-patch`.

However, that file is part of my diff, and was never in the git repo referenced by my patch.

The background is that I created a patch for the master branch.  E.g.

`$ git format-patch origin/master --stdout > ../hyperV-plugin.patch`

The patch itself describes the creation of the file, an applies index 8b8e89d, as show below.

```
1.7.9


From 13f9c118c724afb52b0694de539b4e1b3c38e7f7 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: "U-CC-SVR11\\Administrator" <Administrator@CC-SVR11.(none)>
Date: Thu, 15 Nov 2012 19:19:08 +0000
Subject: [PATCH 07/96] Starting point for ServerResource for Hyper-V is DummyResource.

---
.../com/cloud/agent/resource/HypervResource.java   |  227
++++++++++++++++++++
1 files changed, 227 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-) create mode 100755 agent/src/com/cloud/agent/resource/HypervResource.java

diff --git a/agent/src/com/cloud/agent/resource/HypervResource.java
b/agent/src/com/cloud/agent/resource/HypervResource.java
new file mode 100755
index 0000000..8b8e89d
--- /dev/null
+++ b/agent/src/com/cloud/agent/resource/HypervResource.java
@@ -0,0 +1,227 @@
+// Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one // or 
+more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file // 
+distributed with this work for additional information // regarding 
+copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file // to you under the 
+Apache License, Version 2.0 (the // "License"); you may not use this 
+file except in compliance // with the License.  You may obtain a copy 
+of the License at
```

Later, the file index changes when the file is edited.  E.g.

```
1.7.9


From fef4e3f291264224ed1430b3dff1e49bea7930c9 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: "U-CC-SVR11\\Administrator" <Administrator@CC-SVR11.(none)>
Date: Mon, 19 Nov 2012 15:41:26 +0000
Subject: [PATCH 09/96] Add min messages for host to register with the management server when it starts up.

---
.../com/cloud/agent/resource/HypervResource.java   |  200
++++++++++++++++++-
1 files changed, 189 insertions(+), 11 deletions(-)

diff --git a/agent/src/com/cloud/agent/resource/HypervResource.java
b/agent/src/com/cloud/agent/resource/HypervResource.java
index 8b8e89d..e810ce4 100755
--- a/agent/src/com/cloud/agent/resource/HypervResource.java
+++ b/agent/src/com/cloud/agent/resource/HypervResource.java
@@ -20,14 +20,15 @@ import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.HashMap; import java.util.List; import java.util.Map;
+import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the answer before I got a chance to hit submit on the above question.  Since the answer is not obvious, I will post it here:

**For a multi-commit patch, create  via 'post-review' and not the ReviewBoard GUI.**

The problem is with adding a diff file that aggregates a bunch of patches.  In my case, I've ~97 commits.  Generating a patch for each commit `git format-patch -s master` gives you 97 different patches to review, which is unmanageable.  Apache suggests dumping the patches into a single file with `git format-patch master --stdout > ~/patch-name.patch` (See [Contributing to Apache CloudStack as a Non-Committer](http://incubator.apache.org/cloudstack/develop/non-contributors.html))  Unfortunately, this causes problems when one patch is dependent on another.

To avoid these issues, submit the commits as a single patch via the `post-review` command in RBTools (Review Board Tools, see [install instructions](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/users/tools/post-review/).  After installing RBTools, verify that your local git repo's origin/master is tracking the target for your code merge. E.g.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator-cloudstack.git (fetch)
origin  https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator-cloudstack.git (push)
```

Also, set the target Review Board.  E.g. to set for a repo, use the following command in the repo's root folder.

```
git config reviewboard.url https://reviews.apache.org
```

From the root of your local git repo, simply call `post-review`.  It will gross up the changes between HEAD in the local repo and origin/master, create a review, and return the URL.  You then flesh out the comments/summary/group using a browser.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it could be RB is not presenting the real issue correctly. you can address those `fake` issues one by one. and finally you will see the real issue.

for my case , the real issue is:

```
(1153, "Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes")
```

you cannot post large files (like 6MB) to RB